# Is the difference in HTTPURLConnection behavior between Oracle JDK and OpenJDK intentional or a bug?

Tags: java, java-8

I recently found a difference in the behavior between Oracle JDK and OpenJDK that really surprised me. Maybe someone who is more familiar with the process could explain if this is a bug or a feature.

With release 8u311 ([change log](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/8u311-relnotes.html#JDK-8161016)) Oracle introduced a fix for this issue: [JDK-8161016](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8161016)
In short, if a connection via proxy would not work, the HttpURLConnection class would fall back to a direct connection. With this release, the default behavior was changed to throw an exception instead. As you can see from the change log and the sub-task in the bug tracker on openjdk.org, there should also be a property called `sun.net.http.fallbackToDirect` that re-activates the old behavior if you need it.

I have tested the property in Oracle JDK and the property works fine (<s>unfortunately I don't have an MRE right now</s>). However, with OpenJDK 8u312 (there is no 311 mind you) the property does not work. If we look into the [source code](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk8u/commits/master/jdk/src/share/classes/sun/net/www/protocol/http/HttpURLConnection.java), it looks like only the first sub-task of the above mentioned bug fix was implemented and the second one wasn't. The bug tracker also only is mentioning version 8u311 as the fixed version which does not exist in OpenJDK at all.

So is this difference between the JDKs on purpose or unintended? I wanted to ask here first before reporting it as a bug.

**EDIT 1:**

I have created an MRE based on the test class that was created in the [original bug fix](https://hg.openjdk.org/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/rev/e091a3b3405d). If you run it with Oracle's 8u311 the property works fine, i.e. a timeout on the proxy results in a fallback to a direct connection attempt. With OpenJDK 8u312-b07 (Adoptium build) the property is ignored, i.e. a SocketTimeoutException is thrown. I'm testing on Windows 10.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class ProxyMRE {
    public static void main(String... arg) {
        // Remove the default nonProxyHosts to use localhost for testing
        System.setProperty("http.nonProxyHosts", "");
        System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "1.1.1.1");
        System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "1111");
    
        // Set the fallback property (does not exist in OpenJDK)
        System.setProperty("sun.net.http.fallbackToDirect", "true");

        ServerSocket ss;
        URL url;
        URLConnection con;

        // Test: using Proxy set by System Property
        try {
            ss = new ServerSocket(0);
            url = new URL("http://localhost:" + ss.getLocalPort());
            con = url.openConnection();
            con.setConnectTimeout(10 * 1000);
            con.connect();
            System.out.println("Fallback to DIRECT connection works!");
        } catch (IOException ie) {
            System.out.println("There is no fallback to a DIRECT connection attempt.");
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

I did some additional testing and I tried to understand the chronology of this change. The original fix, i.e. not falling back to a DIRECT connection attempt if the connection via proxy fails, was [introduced](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8161016) in 2016 during the development of Java 9. The [change log](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/9-all-relnotes.html#JDK-8161016) of the first release in 2017 clearly addresses the change and does not mention any property that would allow to reintroduce the fallback.

In 2021 the change was back-ported to Java 7 and 8. This is apparently the point in time when the `sun.net.http.fallbackToDirect` property was introduced. We can see it being mentioned in a [sub-task](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8268881), in the release notes for [8u311](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/8u311-relnotes.html) and [7u321](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/7u321-relnotes.html), but it never made it into the OpenJDK source code. So the above mentioned difference between Oracle JDK and OpenJDK is still present in Java 8 up until the latest release 8u361. In all subsequent Java versions this is not the case.

Comment: I think we NEED a minimal reproducible example to confirm that there *really* is a difference between the OpenJDK an Oracle versions ... as you are claiming. Why?  Because OpenJDK and Oracle JDK are (we are told) built from the same source code.  So, short of a major stuff-up in running the respective builds, it is hard to see how there *could* be a difference like this.  (Note: I haven't looked at the source code for this fix ...)

Comment: And ... you should have a minimal reproducible example before you submit a bug.

Comment: Thank you Stephen. That makes totally sense. I have included an MRE now.

Comment: Thanks.  Hopefully, someone will take the time to reproduce / confirm this for you.  Unfortunately, I don't have a Windows box.  (Sorry.)